# Need to send "msg" file so that it is "previewable"

Tags: microsoft-outlook, attachments

I need to send, via the Outlook Web App, an "msg" file so that it can be previewed by the recipient.  I attach and send, but it only shows up in the received e-mail as a link, and then the recipient has trouble opening it.  Is there a way to attach it so that it can be opened as a "preview"?  (And yes, as strange as it may be, I am pretty sure the preview will work, if I can make it happen.  It's a long story.)

Comment: How did the recipient view the file, via OWA as well or via Outlook desktop client? How does the "link" look like?
Have you tried sending a .msg file to others or yourself and check if it can be previewed probably?

Comment: @YukiSun   It was OWA.  The link is just a little piece of clickable text.  I tried sending to myself and got the same problem with OWA.  For reasons I won't go into, Outlook desktop is not an option.